# how to add a field to default SharePoint newitem form

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, 2016

I want to add an existing field to SharePoint default new item form.

Making the field required adds it to the NewItem form, but when we make it non-mandatory, the field goes away

Is there a way to add the field without requiring it to be mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add that column to content type in order to able to make it available in the form.

While creating column there is a checkbox which says

> Add this to all content types

If you don't want to add it to all, then you have add it explicitly to content type.

Comment: its already added to the content type, but its not showing up in the form unless make it a required field

Comment: Recreated this scenario at my end. Works perfect in my environment.  It must something else which causing it. Are you facing similar issue in other lists as well ? or for newly created column in same list ?

Comment: Its a task list, and I am trying to add the description (body) field to the form

Comment: Can you share screenshot of your column details by going to list setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSOM to add the field into new form.

Here is an example for your reference:

```
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll")

Function Get-SPOContext([string]$Url,[string]$UserName,$Password)
{
    write-host Get-SPOContext   
    $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $Context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $Password) #SecurePassword
    return $Context
}

$UserName = "xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString    
$Url = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Developer"
$listTitle="MyList"
$FieldName="Comment"

$Context = Get-SPOContext -Url $Url -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)
$Context.Load($List)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Retrieve field
$field = $List.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle($FieldName)
$Context.Load($field)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
$field.SetShowInNewForm($true)
$field.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)

$Context.ExecuteQuery()

write-host Done
```